Have the open Questions 1 and 2 from Section 7 of the paper "Integrals with values in Banach spaces" been answered?
Some context: I had previously asked the post below on MSE, but someone suggested I ask it here and delete the original post.

In section 7 of the paper Integrals with values in Banach Spaces and locally convex spaces by Piotr Mikusiński (2014), two open questions are presented:
Question 1: If $f: X \to E$ (where $E$ is a complete locally convex space) and $\pi_\alpha f$ (where $\{|\cdot|\}_\alpha$ is a family of seminorms for the topology of $E$ and $\pi_\alpha$ the projection from $E$ to the quotient normed space $E_\alpha$) is Bochner integrable for every $\alpha \in I$, is $f$ integrable?
Question 2: Is the space $L^1(X, \mu, E)$, which consists of $E$-valued functions that are integrable with respect to a measure $\mu$ on $X$, complete under the topology induced by the family of semi-norms $|\cdot|_\alpha$?
Have these questions been answered since the paper was written? Any updates or references would be appreciated.
